# Adobe's file type icons

Tags: icons

Where can I find a list of Adobe icons? Not for the programs themselves but the recognized file types; i.e. http://blogs.adobe.com/typblography/cs5icons/CS5_file_swf.png.

Where are the .ico files stored on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *official* word is thus:

http://www.adobe.com/misc/linking.html#producticons

Says:

> You may not use Adobe product icons except under a written license from Adobe.You may qualify for use of an Adobe product icon(s) under a program offered through an Adobe Partner program. If you are not eligible for any of these programs, you may be eligible to use one of Adobe's web logos or a box shot of an Adobe product instead.

---

That said, there are a few places on the web with some of the icons, such as http://www.seoconsultants.com/windows/icons/adobe/

Typically in Windows, the icons are embedded in the executable. For example, I used [IcoFx](http://icofx.ro/) to open one of the .exe files and found more than 50 icons in the Photoshop executable alone.